# How to build boost C++ library for smartfox on window phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, boost, smartfoxserver

I use smartfox to develop games on window phone 8, but i can't complie project because boost library of smartfox don't support window phone 8. I found this article and did follow:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/07/18/using-boost-libraries-in-windows-store-and-phone-applications.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments but still problem when i use command:
**b2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=release link=static architecture=arm windows-api=phone**

**Result of command:**

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>cd C:\boost
C:\boost>b2 toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug link=static architecture=arm windows
    -api=phone
    C:/boost/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:262: in find-jamfile from module proj
    ect
    error: Unable to load Jamfile.
    error: Could not find a Jamfile in directory 'libs/config/checks/architecture'.
    error: Attempted to find it with pattern '[Bb]uild.jam [Jj]amfile.v2 [Jj]amfile
    [Jj]amfile.jam'.
    error: Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
    C:/boost/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:280: in load-jamfile from module proj
    ect
    C:/boost/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:64: in load from module project
    C:/boost/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:89: in load-used-projects from module
     project
    C:/boost/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:75: in load from module project
    C:/boost/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:145: in project.find from module proj
    ect
    C:/boost/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:535: in load from module build-system
    C:\boost\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import from module modules
    C:\boost\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
    C:\boost\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
    C:\boost>
```

So any body can help me build boost librabry for window phone, thanks !

Comment: somebody can help me ?, please:(

Answer (score 0):

download the distribution from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.58.0/

Comment: I just tried but still have problem when compling :(

Comment: Error 11 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mswsock.h': No such file or directory (..\..\..\Classes\BaCayChuong.cpp) d:\lamquenvoicocos2dx\cocos2d-x-2.2.6\cocos2d-x-2.2.6\libs\boost\asio\detail\socket_types.hpp 40 1 iCasino_v2Component